# Alexa skill hosted on Web Service using ngrok : This combination of host and port requires TLS

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ngrok

I am trying to host alexa skill on my webservice.

For testing purpose, I am using ngrok to generate https webservice url.
I have added the URL into alexa configuration.

When I try to test the service, I can see my local ngrok server is receiving the request as below.

```
GET /alexa/service/processrequest
Summary
Headers
Raw
Binary
GET /alexa/service/processrequest HTTP/1.1
Host: 9286ef9a.ngrok.io
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Forwarded-For: 49.248.168.79
```

However, its not reaching to my webservice/skill code which I am debugging through eclipse remote breakpoints.
In ngrok, I can see an error below:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
Connection: close

Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS.
```

I have configured spring-boot to run on https port 443 by generating a self signed certificate. The same certificate is uploaded to alexa developer console.

If I hit my webservice url in google chrome using ngrok url, it gives same error:

[image]

But if i use localhost in my url, then chrome is able to detect the https as below:

[image]

I am not able to locate the root cause.
Can anyone here please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found answer to my question and I am posting it so that it can help others to understand what to do in above scenario.

Spring-boot was creating https endpoint for my webservice on port 443.
In chrome, if I hit this port with **https** url, it was working but if i hit this port with **http** url, the error was coming as in above screenshot.
So, overall, **spring-boot was saying that a request is coming to an http** **endpoint** when it was supposed to be received at https endpoint.

The culprit was **NGROK**. :-(

Though, ngrok was creating an https endpoint for public access, it was not creating https tunnel from ngrok client (running on my pc) to tomcat server.
Using -**tls option**, ngrok supports https/tls tunneling but that happens **only in paid plans of ngrok**.

Similar to ngrok, I also explored [localtunnel](https://localtunnel.me/), but it too has the same problem of **tls tunneling**.

**The workaround**

Since, I was doing all this to debug skill development on my local machine, I tried other option of certificate provision mentioned at point 2 [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html#about-ssl-options).
This option allows me to use local web server as http only which now can be well supported by ngrok or localtunnel. :-)

So, following steps I had taken to enable debugging Alexa Skill during developemnt:

1. Use 2nd option of SSL Provisioning in Alexa Web Console.
2. Removed local SSL endpoints and run tomcat on plain http instead of https.
3. Used ngrok https endpoint in Alexa web console.

Answer (score 0):

we can sign up on ngrok and set the authtoken (Steps on https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/your-authtoken)

Then use ngrok http https://localhost:8081, then ngrok forwards it to https

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29902426)